# Accessing current_user in Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, url-routing

Please forgive me... I know there are other posts with a similar title but I have not seen my question so...

I am trying to create a url mysite.com/myusername/profile and I was wondering how to create the route for that. At the moment, the url for user#profile is just that, mysite.com/user/profile, but I want to make it something more specific like say each user has a username like JohnnySmith the URL would be mysite.com/JohnnySmith/profile. I was thinking something like

```
get "/#{current_user.username}", to: "user#profile", as: user_profile
```

but I know this isn't correct.

I should mention that, too, that it is not possible for just anyone to access mysite.com/JohnnySmith/profile.... the current user would have to be JohnnySmith.

Can someone help?  Thanks.

Comment: are you aware how devise works, current_user variable always contains the logged in user resource. Elaborate your question with your trial code

Comment: Its called pretty url checkout the links: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id and this rails casts video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a parameter in a route, it should be

```
get "/:username/profile", to: "user#profile", as: user_profile
```

Please take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Then you can use `params[:username]` in your controller to validate the user like

```
if current_user.username != params[:username]
   # redirect to error page
```

Or you can use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) with [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) for authorization.

---

Essentially, what you're trying to do is allow Rails to process usernames through the params. This can be done without `friendly_id`, but is somewhat hacky.

Using the `friendly_id` gem will allow you to use the following:

```
#Gemfile
gem "friendly_id"

$ rails generate friendly_id
$ rails generate scaffold user name:string slug:string:uniq
$ rake db:migrate

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :username, use: [:finders, :slugged]
end
```

You'd then be able to use:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "", only: [] do
   get :profile, action: :show, on: :member #-> url.com/:id/profile
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This will automatically translate `params[:id]` into the [`slug`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) attribute for the `User` model:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", user_profile_path(current_user) %>
# -> url.com/:current_user_name/profile
```

--

The next stage to this is *authorization*.

Using `CanCanCan` should make it so that only the `current_user` can view their profile:

```
#Gemfile
gem "cancancan"

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :read, User, id: user.id
  end
end
```

You can then use [`load_and_authorize_resource`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#2-check-abilities--authorization) in your `users` controller:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   load_and_authorize_resource

   def show
   end
end
```